# Learn Python the Hard Way Help: Exercise 13

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with the extra credit on Exercise 13 of Learn Python the Hard Way.
It wants me to combine argv with raw_input, which I can't figure out.
Could anyone help me out? Examples would be great!
Thanks so much!
Edit: The original code for the exercise is:

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

Comment: It would be nice if you posted some code for everyone that doesn't have this book sitting on their desks.

Comment: for reference, the exercise being discussed is here: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex13.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an example would be indistinguishable from the answer, which is unlikely to be the best way to help you. perhaps you are overthinking the question, though. i believe the idea is to use some command-line input (which goes into argv) and some entered input (which comes through raw_input) to make a script which reports on both. For example, it might produce:

```
The script is called: ex13.py
Your first variable is: cheese
Your second variable is: apples
You entered the following data: foo bar baz
```

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot more sense than what I was trying to do... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I tried to do it:

```
from sys import argv

script, weather, feeling = argv

print "Hot or Cold",
weather = raw_input()

print "Happy or sad",
feeling = raw_input()

print "The name of the script is:" , script
print "The day is:", weather
print "Today I am feeling:", feeling
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def main():
    all_args = sys.argv[:]
    user = None
    while user != 'STOP':
        user = raw_input('You have %d args stored. Enter STOP or add another: ' % len(all_args))
        if user != 'STOP':
            all_args.append(user)
    print 'You entered %d args at the command line + %d args through raw_input: [%s]' % (len(sys.argv), len(all_args) - len(sys.argv), ', '.join(all_args))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This was confusing to me as well. The author puts this in his faq at the bottom.

Q: I can't combine argv with raw_input().
A: Don't overthink it. Just slap two lines at the end of this script that uses raw_input() to get something and then print it. From that start playing with more ways to use both in the same script.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Not a new question. The author answered the question in the faq below the example. I was just pointing out that the author had already had that question and answered it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this: (note: you still have to provide the arguments when initially running the script)

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = (argv)

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third

first = raw_input("\nNew First Variable? ")
second = raw_input("New Second Variable? ")
third = raw_input("New Last Variable? ")

print "\n\nYour new variables are %s, %s, and %s" % (first, second, third)
```

Here's the output I get:

```
C:\Users\mbowyer\Documents\Python_Work>python ex13a.py 1 2 3


The script is called: ex13a.py

Your first variable is: 1

Your second variable is: 2

Your third variable is: 3

New First Variable? a

New Second Variable? b

New Last Variable? c

Your new variables are a, b, and c

C:\Users\mbowyer\Documents\Python_Work>
```